# Excel list internal hyperlinks on pictures

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this code to list pictures/textboxes with hyperlinks, but it only lists external hyperlinks, is there a way to change it to include internal links as well?

```
    For Each wsSheet In wbBook.Worksheets
    
        wsSheet.Activate
        
        For Each Hint In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        On Error Resume Next
        
            Set hl = Hint.Hyperlink
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not hl Is Nothing Then
               
                Print #intFile, hl.Address
                Set hl = Nothing

            End If
       
        Next

    Next wsSheet
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you consider as external or internal link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must examine both the hyperlink's `Address` and `SubAddress`.  Websites use `Address` and internal links use `SubAddress`

Here is a little sub that loops over all the Shapes on a single worksheet and determines if the `Shape` has a link and what its type is:

```
Sub jhahgdsdsf()
    Dim s As Shape, hy As Hyperlink
    Dim msg As String
    
    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        On Error Resume Next
            Set hy = s.Hyperlink
            x = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If x <> 0 Then
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & s.Name & " " & "has no hyperlink"
        Else
            If hy.Address <> "" Then
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & s.Name & " " & "has hyperlink with address " & hy.Address
            Else
                msg = msg & vbCrLf & s.Name & " " & "has hyperlink with sub-address " & hy.SubAddress
            End If
        End If
    Next s
        
    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]